# Circular motion question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

> *(Q) Find the maximum speed at which a truck can safely travel without toppling over, on a curve of radius 250m. The height of the centre of gravity of the truck above the ground is 1.5m and the distance between the wheels is 1.5m, the truck being horizontal.*

I actually can't figure out which force acts as the centripetal force in the question. Also since it is a truck so it can't lean, so I can't apply the method we generally use in leaning of cycle. Also no friction is described here between the road and wheels.

[image: My progress till now]

Comment: I apologize if my question looks of topic but I have already tried to solve this question several times before asking it here. And also I have just asked an approach for such questions. BTW this isn't a home work, I was just practicing some physics for my upcoming exam.

Comment: Hi Abhishek Verma. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: I apologize again, @Qmechanic, for any violation of rules. But my examinations are knocking my doors and I don't have much time for reading about the homework tag. I hope you will understand. I promise I will read about homework tag after the examinations.

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong with my question, it's just the fact that I don't get much of physics and my examinations are near and that shouldn't be the reason for such a disregard. I respect Lubos for suggesting me an answer. But the answer didn't explain my confusions. Neither I am 'cheating' nor this is an 'homework' question by any means! I had expectations with this site.

Comment: It IS a homework question by the standards of this site. Even though it isn't actual homework it will be tagged homework because: "A "homework question" is any question whose value lies in helping you understand the method by which the question can be solved, rather than getting the answer itself. This includes not just questions from actual homework assignments, but also self-study problems, puzzles, etc."

Comment: And to get you started: think about the location of the center-of-mass of the truck with respect to the point (line) around which it has to rotate to tip over

Comment: A hint, this was exactly what I wanted! Thanks @Michiel. Can you check my progress on the problem I have updated my question.

Comment: You should make sure to understand the difference between centrifugal and centripetal force. Centripetal force is the force applied to an object to keep it moving in a circle. It is always direction *toward* the center of the circle. Centrifugal force is not actually a real force, but an apparent force which appears to act in the frame of the moving object. It is directed *away* from the center of the circle. It is the force that pushes you to the wall of the car when it turns.

Comment: That being if you were on a merry-go-round, do you feel like you are pulled toward the center or pushed away from it? In your picture, do you think the car would topple to the left as if being pulled toward the center or topple to the right as if being pushed away from the center? And as far as the cause of the centripetal force, do you think it would be reasonable for the one who posed the question to leave it implied that friction supplies the centripetal force? When is the last time you have seen a car turn by something other than friction with the road?

Comment: Ok, now I know the difference between them, thanks. I have updated my progress.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to fully solve the homework problems for users because this is not a website for cheating, it's a website helping people to understand physics or make progress with some physics research. But you may find an analogous problem dedicated to the recent train crash in Spain discussed here:

> http://motls.blogspot.com/2013/07/spanish-train-crash-quantifying.html?m=1

Comment: I am afraid that won't help anyway. I have updated the question, can you please have a look at it.